# Spring Boot (Java) - java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry for key another table

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a problem about inserting a new user with its role after adding a user with its role.

I firstly created a user with ROLE_USER and a user with ROLE_ADMIN.

When I tried to create a new with its role, I got **Duplicate entry for key** error.

How can I fix it?

Here is my request body shown below

```
{
    "username" : "admin1",
    "password" : "admin1",
    "email" : "admin1@refreshtoken.com",
    "roles" : [
            "ROLE_ADMIN"
    ]
}
```

Here are classes shown below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Roles")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Role extends IdBasedEntity implements Serializable {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 20, unique = true)
    private ERole name;

    public Role(ERole name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ERole getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User extends IdBasedEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

}

public enum ERole {
    ROLE_USER,
    ROLE_ADMIN
}

@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public class IdBasedEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Integer id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "RefreshToken")
@Data
public class RefreshToken extends IdBasedEntity implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String token;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Instant expiryDate;
}
```

Here is my code snippet shown below.

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {

        String username = signUpRequest.getUsername();
        String email = signUpRequest.getEmail();
        String password = signUpRequest.getPassword();
        Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRoles();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if(userService.existsByUsername(username)){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
        }

        if(userService.existsByEmail(email)){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new MessageResponse("Error: Email is already taken!"));
        }

        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(password));

        if (strRoles != null) {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                switch (role) {
                    case "ROLE_ADMIN":
                        roles.add(new Role(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN));
                        break;
                    default:
                        roles.add(new Role(ERole.ROLE_USER));
                }
            });
        }else{
            roles.add(new Role(ERole.ROLE_USER));
        }

        user.setRoles(roles);
        userService.saveUser(user);  // ERROR LINE

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
    }
```

Here is my error shown below.

```
// Create User
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'ROLE_USER' for key 'roles.UK_ofx66keruapi6vyqpv6f2or37'
// Create Admin
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'ROLE_ADMIN' for key 'roles.UK_ofx66keruapi6vyqpv6f2or37'
```

Comment: Please provide additional information about recent code changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove CascadeType.ALL from User.roles. Roles should only be referenced, not owned.

Roles need to be created and stored just once, best with some database script. In your code, load all available roles, put them in a Map and add required roles to the users. Never create roles with new Role(...).

Comment: I removed it then I got this issue. `org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.microservice.authservice.model.Role`

Comment: You need to store both roles first, load them and add some of them to a user. Roles should be modelled as Flightweight objects: there is only one instance of role ADMIN and just one instance of role USER.

Comment: I already stored ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER in the database before creating a new user.

Comment: I added a paragraph to adress this issue.

Comment: How can I define role in roles.add?

Comment: You need to add a role that you loaded from the database.

Comment: I already did that in strRoles part. I also shared request body.